# Is it correct to say/write "In colonial times Quetta was known as little London because of its clean and organized urban sprawl"

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say/write "Did you know that in colonial times Quetta was known as little London because of its clean and organized urban sprawl"

Is it correct to say "clean and organized urban sprawl" or "clean and organized urban area"?

What I want to say is that the city was not as unruly in colonial times as it is at present. How do I put that into words instead of using sprawl? Kindly give some advice

Comment: "organized urban sprawl" is being ironic, because "urban sprawl" is by nature disorganized. Is that what you want?

Comment: What I want to say is that the city was not as unruly in colonial times as it is at present. How do I put that into words instead of using sprawl? Kindly give some advice.

Comment: That's a good sentence you have already--"the city was not as unruly in colonial times as it is at present".  Was London clean and organized in colonial times? The Wikipedia article says it's beauty and geographical location that are responsible for the comparison.